# How can I create an AMI that uses password authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, sshd

My goal is to spin up an EC2 instance, make an AMI from that instance, use the custom AMI to spin up a new instance that uses password authentication instead of keys.

I changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have `PasswordAuthentication yes` before creating the AMI, but I still get "permission denied (publickey)" when trying to SSH to the new instance created from the custom AMI.

I followed [these steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/) and they work on the first instance, but then I still get the error when logging into the instance created from the customn AMI.

Comment: https://www.cloudtern.com/create-aws-ami-with-custom-ssh-username-and-password/ Kindly use the steps mentioned in the above link

Comment: Please read my original post. I followed identical instructions to those from AWS docs and am still having the problem. Interestingly enough I had already found the article you posted in my initial troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

AWS support fixed my problem, here is their answer:

> Make changes to the following lines in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg file on
>   the original instance launched in the above steps as follows:
>
> ---
>
> Default
>   settings:
>
> ssh_pwauth:  0
>
> lock_passwd: true
>
> ---
>
> Settings after modification:
>
> ssh_pwauth:  1
>
> lock_passwd: false
>
> ---
>
> `service sshd restart`
>
> ---
>
> REFERENCES
>
> https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#including-users-and-groups
>
> https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html

Comment: The key here was cloud.cfg which is not mentioned in any of their docs or at least I couldn't find